# Rhino for Android

Tags: android, rhino

I am trying to use rhino in my android project following  [this](https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/rhino-android/blob/master/examples/Control.java). I dawnloaded Rhino and added `js.jar` in `lib`.
Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        Context rhino = Context.enter();
//        try{                     // I commented it to catch the error
            rhino.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_2);
            Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
            Object result=rhino.evaluateString(scope, 
                           "obj={a:1,b:['x','y']}", "MySource", 1, 
                            null);       // This line cannot be compiled

            Scriptable obj = (Scriptable)scope.get("obj",scope);
            Log.i("JS","obj " + (obj == result ? "==" : "!=") +" result");

            Log.i("js","obj.a == " + obj.get("a", obj));


            Scriptable b = (Scriptable) obj.get("b", obj);
//        }catch (Exception e){
//            Log.e("js","Exception.....");
//        }
     }
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.behy.jsinand, PID: 7027
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.behy.jsinand/com.behy.jsinand.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.DefiningClassLoader.defineClass(DefiningClassLoader.java:27)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.defineClass(Codegen.java:130)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.createScriptObject(Codegen.java:85)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1335)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1324)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1076)
    at com.behy.jsinand.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

It is complately based on the sample project but I dont undrestand why it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it (and post the answere maybe it's helpful for you)
The project linked in the question is not for Android application. 
To compile it in android, you should set the `optimizationLevel` of your `Context` to `-1`:
     rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);

and it works!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a library which allows using Rhino on Android with no constraints for the optimzation level.

https://github.com/F43nd1r/rhino-android